# magic_quotes help

Tags: php

Recently I have been faced with the problematics that magic_quotes provides. I did notice that there were 3 different type(s) however which does what?

- magic_quotes_gpc
- magic_quotes_runtime
- magic_quotes_sybase

I know it's always good practice to do a check for enabled magic quotes but which ones should be check if not just GPC?

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc() || get_magic_quotes_runtime()) {
    $string = stripslashes($string);    
}
```

I want to be able to have something similar to this that runs in any code that I do so that way if ever an issue with the server I am working with it will fix any magic quote issues.

How would you guys/girls perform the check that's successful or is this completely correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

magic_quotes_gpc() applies to data coming from (G)ET, (P)OST, and (C)OOKIEs

magic_quotes_runtime() applies to data coming in from ANY source (file_get_contents(), fread(), etc...)

magic_quotes_sybase switches between escaping with a single quote (`'`) and a backslash (`\`), as not all databases use backslashes for escaping (like sybase).

Comment: magic_quotes_gpc is EGPCS now: (E)NVironment, (G)ET, (P)OST, (C)OOKIEs, (S)ESSION.

Comment: So I only really need the GPC? I am only calling the escape when inserting into database.

Comment: @tjmoore: You should not be so relax about the attack and only use magic quotes in the GPC(get post and cookie) you should also use the magic quotes in all incoming input for more detail please go to http://www.abwad.com/phpart/1-tutorial/44-magic-quotes-in-php.html

Comment: @ankur: You're missing the point complete. never EVER use magic quotes. Use functions designed to escape data for the specific purpose you're using the data. mysql_real_escape_string() for mysql database operations, htmlspecialchars()/htmlentities() for html insertion, urlencode() for URL building, etc... magic quotes are toxic waste and should be buried and never ever used again.